# C# struct array inside a function

Tags: c#, function, struct

I'm trying out structures and I can't figure out how to use them inside of functions.
Later on I'll need to develop a piece of code that'll allow me to add students and reenter some details.

```
namespace struct_example
{
    struct student
    {
        public int s_id;
        public String s_name, c_name, s_dob;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            student[] arr = new student[4];

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                fillplz(i);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                showplz(i);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static void fillplz(int id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter StudentId, StudentName, CourseName, Date-Of-Birth");
            arr[id].s_id = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            arr[id].s_name = Console.ReadLine();
            arr[id].c_name = Console.ReadLine();
            arr[id].s_dob = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void showplz(int id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr[id].s_id);
            Console.WriteLine(arr[id].s_name);
            Console.WriteLine(arr[id].c_name);
            Console.WriteLine(arr[id].s_dob);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly the problem you are having is? Is this code throwing an error or refusing to compile or something else?

Comment: Well first of all by first glance arr is an array in the scope of Main only

Comment: well it's returning 0's

Comment: fillplz and showplz cannot access arr[]

Comment: No,I don't think so. This code won`t compile

Comment: Your implementation is correct, just make arr accessible to fillplz and showplz by passing it into the functioon or by making it global

Comment: Oh well, you're right. It won't compile.
I added student[] arr = new student[4]; inside of the fillplz() and showplz(), then it returned 0's

Comment: That's because you are creating new variables with the same names that is accessible in each respective scope

Comment: just do `public student[] arr = new student[4];` outside of the functions

Comment: why is student a struct instead of a class ?  Student should not be a value type, it is an entity and thus a class is more suitable.

Comment: I would agree with @FrederikGheysels here. At the moment you seem to be a novice in C# judging by the simple errors you've made here. As a rule of thumb until you really know the difference between struct and class just use classes for everything.

Answer (score 3):

The only problem in your code is that you are trying to access `arr` when it isn't in scope.

You have declared `arr` in your `Main` method which means it is only accessible there. If you declared it as a field on your class then you would be able to access it and everything would work as you expected. Alternatively you could pass the array as a parameter to the methods that use it and access it that way.

In short: the problem is nothing to do with structs, it is to do with scoping your variables and you would have run into similar problems with a class.

An additional note: When I compiled your code (and well done for giving an easily compilable code sample) I got errors such as:

> error CS0103: The name 'arr' does not exist in the current context

And would have included exact line numbers and should have told you exactly how to fix your error.